# Diawi iOS IPA upload failed

Tags: ios, ipa, diawi

I am getting below error from last 24 hours during IPA upload through Diawi distribution web site -

> An error occurred: This request requires an access token, but none was
>   provided (#400)

Please refer attach screenshot. I have tried with some old IPA which works with Diawi few days ago but same error

Thanks in advance for your help.

[image]

Comment: Yesterday i was also facing the same error message.

Comment: checkout my answer. its work correctly

Comment: try https://buildtry.com

Answer (score 3):

This same problem i was faced in mozila firefox. Its works fine in google chrome try with chrome for uploading. Once its done, its alerts the uploading is done successfully.

You have to load this page completely and its showing you process of loading in upper side of page. once this loading done its showing you upload ipa option in uploading area.

Comment: I think this is not mozila or chrome issue. Because I have faced same problem in chrome.

Comment: if its not working in device then its issues based on your provisioning profile section. otherwise if you cant able to generate iPA then its issue based on browser because its work fine for me

Comment: if issues is not with profile then clear your browser cookie and history or reset and then try to check once again with google chrome browser and generate iPA. i hope its work for you.

Answer (score 3):

If you find issues and want some alternative then, these two would be great options, Even it will give you permission to upload **IPA greater than 100 mb**.

1) [SendOTA.com](http://sendota.com)

2) [DeployNinja.com](http://www.deployninja.com)

3) [InstallonAir.com](https://www.installonair.com/)

Answer (score 2):

**Working now.**
I had the same issue. I switch to "SAFARI" browser. And it works. 
Please try safari browser.

Answer (score 1):

Try changing your browser or Clear cache and cookies of current browser and you will be able to upload the app to Diawi.

Comment: I use the safari for build and now its successfully created.

Answer (score 0):

You should  check  that you select generic type at time of build or if you are using ipa then regenerate it. it happen some time

Answer (score 0):

Try changing your browser to safari or Clear cache and cookies of current browser and you will be able to upload the app to Diawi.

Answer (score 0):

for this problem you can use "incognito mode" (google chrome, SHIFT+CMD+N).

Answer (score 0):

There might be an issue with the way XCode 9 is building the app. Instead of using the IPA file do the following:

1. Set the active scheme to generic iOS Device
2. Clean the project (Product->Clean)
3. Build (Product->Build)
4. In project manager, find the '.app' file. Right click and 'show in Finder'
5. Right click on the file in Finder and compress it to make a zip file
6. Drag the zip file into Diawi to create your build

Answer (score 0):

This same problem i was faced in chrome. Its works fine in Safari try with Safari for uploading.